# Normalizing and storing boolean expressions (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, boolean, expression, normalize

I have Boolean expression that represent queries which users can enter. They contain brackets and the AND, NOT and OR operators. Example:

```
(A1 OR B1) AND (NOT C2)
```

For clarification: The expression describes a biological state that can consist of a combination of other parts. E.g.,

```
"(has mutation in gene X) OR (has mutation in gene Y AND has mutation in gene Z)".
```

I need to store it in a way such that if users enter different expressions that describe the same state, I can see they are identical (e.g., `A OR A` should be normalized to `A`).

I would like to normalize them and later store the normalized version in a database.

My questions are: 
1) How should I save them (strings, tree-like structure)?
2) How should I normalize them based on the saved notation?

Through Google searching I have found references to the Quine–McCluskey algorithm. Would this method be suitable?

Comment: asking for tools is OT.

Comment: where do you evaluate the expression?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I have updated the question with more information. I only need to store and retrieve them in a normalized way.

Comment: i would use the smallest possible string. in the aboce case, i would store only `'(A1 OR B1) AND NOT C2'` and parse it for use later.

Comment: For others reading this: We ended up doing this in Python in the backend. There are some excellent Python packages which will do exactly what I needed, e.g., the Boolean module of SymPy.